# Take external content Uri of an image storage in device's memory

Tags: java, android, image, filepath

I'm working for an App Android on platform Android Studio.
I want to obtain the external content Uri of an image, in form of:

```
content://media/external/images/media
```

The image is stored in mem device. I've only the resource's path, in form of:

```
file://data/data/com.example.appName/files/myimage.png**
```

There is a method or function for doing that?

Comment: No there is not. Unless you show the user that picture and then ask the user to pick the same from the gallery. But then: why do you want such?

Comment: Ehhh... Its complete impossible as the MediaStore cannot scan pictures from your apps internal private memory. So it will not be in the Gallery app too.

Comment: `file://data/data/com.example.appName/files/myimage.png` ??? You mean: `file:///data/data/com.example.appName/files/myimage.png`.

Comment: Yes. So, it isn't really possible?